# Keeps on getting terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'

Tags: c++

```
bool GameUtil::isValidPath(std::vector<int>& path, Player* player, Game* game) {
    ///**Get borad*/
    std::vector<Square*>  board = game->getBoard();
    int maxDistanceTravel = 0;
    int playerCanTravel = 0;
    //first square and last square must be present
    if (path[0] == 0 && path[path.size() - 1] == (board.size() - 1)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < path.size() - 1; i++) {
            /**Max distance of each board from player*/
            maxDistanceTravel = compute(board.at(path[i]), player);
            playerCanTravel = path[i + 1] - path[i];
            if ((playerCanTravel > maxDistanceTravel) && (playerCanTravel <= 0)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I am a new c++ learner and I am getting the same error over and over again but could not figure out what is wrong with it, it is not obviously an out of range, please help, thanks.

Comment: Start by running in a debugger to catch the exception, and locate where in your code it's thrown. Then look at the index being used and you will find that it's out of bounds.

Comment: how do I actually debug this code?

Comment: so at which line are you getting an error?  if you don't have a debugger, you can comment out some of your code first. Print the size of path and board.

Comment: I am not too sure which line is throwing this error either. probably the board.size()-1?

Comment: To debug you first of all you need to build a debug version. In an IDE (like e.g. Visual Studio) you select the "Debug" target, and if your compiling from the command line with e.g. GCC then add the flag `-g`. If you work in an IDE you then select "Run in debugger" or similar option, while from the command line you could use the command `gdb` to load and run the program. If you search a little there are many tutorials and online documentation.

Comment: You check that the first and last squares are present, but what about the intermediate squares? `board.at(path[i])` is a clear suspect here, one that obviously *can* throw an `out_of_range` exception.

Answer (score 0):

I would first try doing some early checking to make sure you're inputs are valid.  Perhaps something like:

```
bool GameUtil::isValidPath(std::vector<int>& path, Player* player, Game* game) {
  assert(!path.empty());
  if (path.size() < 2) return false; // or whatever your minimum size is.
```

As long as you're at it, you should probably scrub the other inputs.

```
bool GameUtil::isValidPath(std::vector<int>& path, Player* player, Game* game) {
  assert(!path.empty());
  assert(game);
  assert(player);
  if (path.size() < 2) return false; // or whatever your minimum size is.
```

I have a rule of thumb to use references for arguments that should never be null.  It looks like in your code that game isn't allowed to be null.  So perhaps you could change the function:

```
bool GameUtil::isValidPath(std::vector<int>& path, Player& player, Game& game) {
  assert(!path.empty());
  if (path.size() < 2) return false; // or whatever your minimum size is.
```

And then change where you call.  So probably in your code you have something like:

```
// somewhere buried in your code:
Game * myGame = .../// however you created it.
Game * myPlayer = .../// however you created it.
GameUtil * myGameUtil = .../// however you created it.
...
auto isValid = myGameUtil->isValidPath(path, myPlayer, myGame);
```

You change it to:

```
// somewhere buried in your code:
Game * myGame = .../// however you created it.
Game * myPlayer = .../// however you created it.
GameUtil * myGameUtil = .../// however you created it.
...
auto isValid = myGameUtil->isValidPath(path, *myPlayer, *myGame);
```

Hope that helps.